# Printing a particular print statement just once

Tags: java, printing, println, system.out

In a collection of print statements how to print a particular statement just once?

Example :

```
public static void nameHere (arguments)
{
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath,true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, "); //I want to print this satement only once
                pw.print(dateFormat.format(date));


                    if (condition 1)
                    {
                        pw.println("Print STmt1");
                    }
                    else if (condition 2)
                    {
                        pw.println("Print STmt1");

                    }
                    else if (Condition 3)
                    {
                        pw.println("Print STmt1");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pw.println("Print STmt1");
                    }

                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
}
```

This actually appends the log to the CSV file mentioned in "filepath" and I just want to print the line "pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, ");" only once although I invoke the program many times.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Keep track of whether you have printed the statement (e.g. with a boolean), and check that boolean's value before printing it again.

Comment: Don't pass `true` in the constructor of `FileWriter`. It will overwrite the content as many times as program is being invoked.

Comment: you execute the program several times or the method? if its the whole program, use a .properties file which contains a value on which you can decide if the statement got already printed

Comment: If you want to run the program multiple times, but only print this once, I'll consider adding a command line argument to indicate whether or not it should be printed.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'll execute just the method several times.

Comment: @SanketMakani I don't get it. Can you please elaborate it with an example?  Also how this would help in printing a particular statement just once? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ManojOffo You should use this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File)) for `FileWriter` instead of the one you are using which appends the existing file.

Comment: @SanketMakani actually I want to append as the method will be invoked more than once, but excluding that print statement in second and consecutive invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static boolean wasPrinted = false;

public static void nameHere(arguments) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
    if (!wasPrinted) {
        pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, ");
        wasPrinted = true;
    }
    pw.print(dateFormat.format(date));

    if (cond 1) {
        pw.println("Print STmt1");
    } else if (cond 2) {
        pw.println("Print STmt1");

    } else if (cond 3) {
        pw.println("Print STmt1");

    } else {
        pw.println("Print STmt1");
    }

    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

edited your code as you posted it and add the check you need to do

Comment: But this code is executing the statement "pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, ");" each and everytime nameHere() method is invoked if I initialize wasPrinted to false. And if I initialize it to true it doesn't print that statement at all.

Comment: "I just want to print the line "pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, ");" only once although I invoke the program many times" That flag will not persist between program invocations.

Comment: @tobias_k he stated in some comment that he only executes the method several times but not the whole program

Comment: @ManojOffo then you have another bug in your code as this solution works perfectly fine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer actually the nameHere() is a method where this method receives arguments like filepath etc., when called.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple flag file.

If this file doesn't exists, it means print statement isn't executed. Print it and create a file.

If this file exists, it means print statement is executed. Don't print anything.

```
File file = new File("flag.txt");
if(!file.exists()) { 
    pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, "); //I want to print this satement only once
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Comment: @XtremeBaumer how can I check w.r.t PrintWriter , FileWriter?

Comment: @RamanSahasi as op now clarified, he only executes the method several times, so your previous solution was fine

Comment: Good idea, but instead of a separate flag file, why not use the file to write to itself? It it does not exist, create it and write the header, then (and otherwise) write the new lines.

Comment: @tobias_k if the file doesn't exists initially, then that would be a perfect idea.

Comment: @RamanSahasi I executed the following :  File f = new File(filepath);
      if(!f.exists()) { 
       pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, "); 
       f.createNewFile();
      }                                                                                 but still it didn't print the line "A , B, C, D, E, F, G,".

Comment: @ManojOffo can you confirm that your application isn't throwing any exception, Because I just compiled the code my self and it's working fine here.

Comment: @RamanSahasi I checked its not throwing any exception but still its not printing "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,";                                                                    
                ...
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath,true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);                                            if(!file.exists()) { 
                pw.println("A , B, C, D, E, F, G, ");                                                 file.createNewFile();}

Comment: @ManojOffo where have you initialized `file` object in `if(!file.exists()) { `?